# twitter4j: No route to hostRelevant exception occured

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

My app using twitter4j lib to send out tweet. But The below exception occasional.I do not know why.
I didn't use proxy.

> status code=-1, Exception detail:No route to hostRelevant discussions can be on the Internet at:
>   http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=b2b52c28 or
>   http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=1b442895
>   TwitterException{exceptionCode=[b2b52c28-1b442895 b2b52c28-1b44286b], statusCode=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, featureSpecificRateLimitStatus=null, version=2.2.5}
>   2012-04-17 17:50:31,320 ERROR [Thread-4135 - TwitterService.java:57] error stack trace:
>   No route to hostRelevant discussions can be on the Internet at:
>   http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=b2b52c28 or
>   http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=1b442895
>   TwitterException{exceptionCode=[b2b52c28-1b442895 b2b52c28-1b44286b], statusCode=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, featureSpecificRateLimitStatus=null, version=2.2.5}
>   at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:200)